# How can I have a step in a makefile to generate preprocess files and compile from those files?

Tags: makefile, c-preprocessor, avr

I took a makefile from a previous project that compiles programs for an avr microcontroller. I ran into some problems with what IO ports/data directional addresses I was setting which was causing the microcontroller to fault and reset. Because of this I wanted to add a step in my makefile to have it generate the pre-proccessed files and then compile from these preprocessed files. I'm not too familiar with how rules/dependencies work in makefiles so I've made, what I believe is, a simple mistake in my understanding of how makefiles work. My rules to make the preprocessed files/object files and eventually the .elf file must be wrong. Up until I added the steps which attempted to create the preprocessed files creating the .elf file work fine. What is my simple mistake/understanding in how rules/dependencies work in make?

How I view this working is when I ask to `make all` it sees that it has a dependency of led.elf. To create this it has the dependency of the preprocessed files based on the line of `$(OUTPUT).elf: $(PROCESS_FILES)` so it starts with this line. When I try to `make all` however I get the error `make: *** No rule to make target 'main.c', needed by 'main.e'.  Stop.` and I don't understand why. Can anyone help my understanding in make files?

```
SRC_FILES=\
main.c led.c comm.c
#Object files
PROCESS_FILES=$(SRC_FILES:.c=.e)
OBJ_FILES=$(PROCESS_FILES:.e=.o)
#Directories where to look for include files
INC_DIRS=\
-I. \
#Output file name
OUTPUT=led
#Programmer and port
PROG=dragon_isp

PORT=usb
#Debugging host and port
DHOST=localhost
DPORT=6423  
#Compiler related params
MCU=atmega2560
CC=avr-gcc
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy
CFLAGS= -mcall-prologues -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned bitfields \
-fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mmcu=$(MCU) -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes \
$(INC_DIRS)
#Optimization level
CFLAGS+=-Os
#Debug info
CFLAGS+=-gdwarf-2

#Generate hex file ready to upload
all: $(OUTPUT).elf
$(OBJCOPY) -R .eeprom -O ihex $(OUTPUT).elf $(OUTPUT).hex                           
#Link output files
$(OUTPUT).elf: $(PROCESS_FILES)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(OUTPUT).elf -Wl,-Map,$(OUTPUT).map
#Create object files
$(PROCESS_FILES): %.e : %.c
  $(CC) -E $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
$(OBJ_FILES): %.o : %.e
  $(CC) -x $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
#Create assembler file of a C source
%.s: %.c
  $(CC) -S $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
#Cleans all generated files
clean:
  rm -f $(OBJ_FILES)
  rm -f $(OUTPUT).elf
  rm -f $(OUTPUT).hex
  rm -f $(OUTPUT).map
```

Edit: I'm away from my computer now so I can't check this but thinking about my issue I'm starting to think I don't have a file named main.c in that directory. Even if I did I still think the makefile would not work correctly because I don't fully understand rules in makefiles.

Comment: The error you posted is make telling you it can't find `main.c`, where are the source files relative to the makefile? Also it isn't clear why you need the extra preprocessing step, please elaborate.

Comment: I use to work a project at a company where the makefiles were much more elaborate and complicated. They had many steps to them and one step was to create the preprocessed files so you could inspect them if you wanted. I liked this and I know it's possible so I want to incorporate it into my project. As of right now it would be useful to see what a specific macro in avr/io.h is being translated into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was coming from the fact that I did not have a `main.c` file in my directory. Make sure you backup files when you're messing with the OBJ_FILES or similar variable and have a line that will delete whatever is in that variable upon a `make clean`.

As for the rules, I had to make one small fix to achieve what I wanted. I changed

```
$(OUTPUT).elf: $(PROCESS_FILES)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(OUTPUT).elf -Wl,-Map,$(OUTPUT).map
```

to

```
$(OUTPUT).elf: $(OBJ_FILES)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $(OUTPUT).elf -Wl,-Map,$(OUTPUT).map
```

This then sees it needs the object files which in turn needs the preprocessed files.

Edit: I also changed `OBJ_FILES=$(PROCESS_FILES:.e=.o)` to `OBJ_FILES=$(SRC_FILES:.c=.o)`. I also added `$(PROCESS_FILES)` to `$(OUTPUT).elf: $(OBJ_FILES)` so the rule would generate both the preprocessed files and object files independently. I had to change `$(OBJ_FILES): %.o : %.e` to `$(OBJ_FILES): %.o : %.c` to make this work.